# Magento 2 Cart Breaking When Copying minicart.phtml into Template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, mini-cart

I want to make some style changes to the mini cart in Magento 2. Mainly move it up with my search bar and change the background color. I have tried using the exact code from the minicart.phtml in the blank template in my template. When I modify the minicart.phtml I am able to style and move it, but my cart no long shows when items have been added and displays blank text when it is clicked. Is there another way I should go about moving / styling my mini cart?

[image]